# Extract numbers from cells of varying lengths/formats

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, min

I am looking for a formula to extract digits from column A.  The problem I am running into is the varying lengths and formats.  I am seeking a solution based on the desired result column below.

Formula in Column B:

```
=IFERROR(INT(LEFT(REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"-"," "),1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A4&1/17))-1,""),5)),INT(LEFT(REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"-"," "),1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A4&1/17))-1,""),4)))
```

Workbook:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: How do you know what the desired results are, is it always the last number in the cell?

Comment: yes, but the cells vary in format and characters making a right or left function too hard to generate.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's do-able.  Logic is to read from the right and find the first number character (get index for that character) and then keep going until you find the next *NOT* a number (get index for that character) and then extract the text between those indices with a `MID` function.  fiddly to to with a single cell formula, but can be done.  I'd suggest spitting out the intermediary calculation steps into other cells, and then work out how to combine into a single cell formula later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function LastNumber(s As String) As Variant
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, temp As String, arr
    Dim CH As String

    L = Len(s)
    temp = ""
    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Then
            temp = temp & CH
        Else
            temp = temp & " "
        End If
    Next i

    arr = Split(Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(temp), " ")
    For i = UBound(arr) To LBound(arr) Step -1
        If IsNumeric(arr(i)) Then
            LastNumber = CLng(arr(i))
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    LastNumber = ""

End Function
```

[image]

It will return the last number *(set of numerals)* in a string.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Awesome solution - only issue I noticed is if the last number (in the rare case) has a leading zero (for example, `Z.ACE.3700.0111.USA` would return `111`). Probably a rare case but I'm not sure what he's trying to parse above.

Comment: @dwirony  If the Poster needs the number as a string *(to preserve leading zeros)*, it is an easy change.

Answer (score 2):

Try this user defined function in a standard public module code sheet.

```
function lastNumber(str as string)
    dim i as long, tmp as string

    tmp = str

    for i=len(tmp) to 1 step-1
        if asc(right(tmp, 1))<48 or asc(right(tmp, 1))>57 then
            tmp = left(tmp, len(tmp)-1)
        else
            exit for
        end if
    next i

    for i=len(tmp) to 1 step-1
        if asc(mid(tmp, i))<48 or asc(mid(tmp, i))>57 then
            exit for
        end if
    next i

    lastNumber = mid(tmp, i+1)
end function
```

Comment: I'm trying really hard to break this code somehow but I can't  >:[ Nice job

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex, which needs a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions:

```
Public Function GetLastNum(str As String) As String
    Dim numRegEx As RegExp
    Set numRegEx = New RegExp

    Dim matchColl As MatchCollection
    Dim retStr As String
    With numRegEx
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[0-9]+"
        Set matchColl = .Execute(str)
        If matchColl.Count > 0 Then
            GetLastNum = matchColl.Item(matchColl.Count - 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With
End Function
```